# How do I make a simple jQuery nested ul list menu

Tags: jquery

I need some jQuery to cause a nested ul list menu to collapse and uncollapse on clicking

```
<ul>
    <li><a href "#">Hello World</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href "#">Hello World</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href "#">Hello World</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href "#">Hello World</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href "#">Hello World</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href "#">Hello World</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href "#">Hello World</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href "#">Hello World</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href "#">Hello World</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this jQuery does the trick:

```
$('li a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ullist = $(this).parent().children('ul:first');
    ullist.toggle('slow');
    //if(ullist.is(':visible')){
    //    ullist.hide('slow');
    //} else {
    //    ullist.show('slow');
    //}
});
```

[see this link on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisseanhayes/Pf6Wv/)

Comment: Your if/else block could be replaced by `ullist.toggle('slow');`, making the code a little simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Try this it give you real collapse uncollapse effect:

```
$('li a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ullist = $(this).parent().children('ul:first');
    ullist.slideToggle();
});
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yPnnM/)